# Does CRNN use sparse tensor value for its label?

Tags: deep-learning, cnn, rnn, ocr

I just read [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.05717.pdf) about cnn + rnn for text recognition. The labels of dataset is tensor of char index (e.g [0, 1, 2 ] for image with label "abc").  Since the label of each input has different length do I need to convert the label to sparse tensor value ? since the paper does not mention about it.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption here is that if the input vectors are of variable length, you should use something like keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences  (as well as a masking layer to ignore these padded values) as a means of reformatting all input samples to the same size so that the input to your recurrent model meets the requirement of having a fixed num_timesteps length.
[Function Documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/):

> Pads sequences to the same length.
>
> This function transforms a list of num_samples sequences (lists of
> integers) into a 2D Numpy array of shape (num_samples, num_timesteps).
> num_timesteps is either the maxlen argument if provided, or the length
> of the longest sequence otherwise.
>
> Sequences that are shorter than num_timesteps are padded with value at
> the end.
>
> Sequences longer than num_timesteps are truncated so that they fit the
> desired length. The position where padding or truncation happens is
> determined by the arguments padding and truncating, respectively.